# C# Get results from SQL query in a text box

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have the following code (no errors) which should get the result of the SQL query and put it in the `HolEmpName` text box, but it remains blank.

```
public void holidayempname()    
{
    string query = "SELECT 'Employee Name' FROM dbo.Employees WHERE EmployeeID = @HolidayEmployeeID;";

    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection())
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@HolidayEmployeeID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = holiday_EmployeeIDTextBox.Text;
        cn.Open();
        object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        cn.Close();
        if (result != null)
        {
            int value = (int)result;
            HolEmpName.Text = value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Table Structure:

Employees:

```
EmployeeID
Employee Name
```

Holidays:

```
HolidayID
Holiday EmployeeID
```

Current Code:

```
    public void holidayempname()

    {
        string query = "SELECT [Employee Name] FROM dbo.Employees WHERE EmployeeID = @HolidayEmployeeID;";

        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection())
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@HolidayEmployeeID", holiday_EmployeeIDComboBox.Text);
            //cmd.Parameters.Add("@HolidayEmployeeID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = holiday_EmployeeIDComboBox.Text;
            cn.Open();
            object result = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            cn.Close();
            if (result != null)
            {
                int value = (int)result;
                HolEmpName.Text = value.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @HolidayEmployeeID;";    Is the ; the issue?

Comment: Debug.Writeline the holiday_EmployeeIDTextBox.Text and see what it outputs. I too suspect that may not be populated, making your query return no result.

Comment: @SANM2009 removed it, still no result.

Comment: @JeremyMorgan Not sure how to do that?

Comment: if you `SELECT 'Employee Name'` then your query result should only give you string `Employee Name` and not the actual row value - is that what you are seeing?

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius I'm not seeing anything, the box is blank

Comment: @Matt put a breakpoint in your code and see if it is ever hit (set a breakpoint where you are setting textbox value)

Comment: `ExecuteScalar` returns the first column of the first row. Is the first column data type an integer? Why do you need to cast result to an integer and then to a string? Why not just do `result.ToString()`

Comment: @TomFarley modified an answer from another post on here, didnt write it form scratch

Comment: The result is probably null - debug that.

Comment: Is the first column an ID column or is it the employee name column? Make the changes I suggested and let me know what you see. Also, it's typically considered bad practice to have spaces in Table names

Comment: Where did you set your ConnectionString?

Comment: @daniel.shih If the initial SQL connection was an issue it would throw an exception rather than go silent. I think this was a typecasting issue.

Comment: @TomFarley if the code got to the type cast it would probably throw as well. ExecuteScalar returns null if there is no 1st row/column

Comment: @user6144226 The result shouldnt be null as there are values in both tables

Comment: @Matt Can you please post your table structure? And if you have access, change your column name to EmployeeName (remove the space)

Comment: @TomFarley Added them

Comment: @Matt Try changing the parameter line to just cmd.Parameters.Add("@HolidayEmployeeID", holiday_EmployeeIDTextBox.Text); omit the database type specification.

Comment: Also if your end goal is to retrieve employee name, you're going to need to use `ExecuteReader()` instead of `ExecuteScalar()`

Comment: Column names are not surrounded by single quotes as @VidmantasBlazevicius has noticed. If your column has spaces you use `[]`, like `[Employee Name]`.

Comment: @TomFarley Tried both and no change

Comment: @Crowcoder tried this and didnt change it but i will keep it in there and amend question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change your code to something like this. The result will be the literal string "Employee Name"

```
    string query = "SELECT 'Employee Name' FROM dbo.Employees WHERE EmployeeID = @HolidayEmployeeID";

    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection())
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@HolidayEmployeeID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = holiday_EmployeeIDTextBox.Text;
        cn.Open();
        dim result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        cn.Close();
        HolEmpName.Text = result.ToString();        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the literal string `Employee Name` instead of a column.

```
string query = "SELECT 'Employee Name' FROM dbo.Employees WHERE EmployeeID = @HolidayEmployeeID;";
```

Comment: I would assume that would then return `Employee Name` rather than blank

Comment: It could also be that your query returns no records, could you add a breakpoint inside the if, so you know it is entered?

Answer (score -5):

I believe the setting of your parameter is the issue.

You need to remove the @ symbol, i.e.

cmd.Parameters.Add("HolidayEmployeeID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = holiday_EmployeeIDTextBox.Text;

Comment: No, @ symbols are usually used to identify the parameter in the sql text.

Comment: @ symbol is required. That's not the issue